# Interrupt all mousedown events to simulate like a mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, click

I want to trigger click event on a element when mousedown occurs. Also, I want to enable this feature for all elements in a html page.

Is it possible with jQuery on Chrome ?

Here's my first attempt;

```
$.fn.mousedown = function (onclick) {
    this.bind("click", function (e) { onclick.call(this, e); });  
    return this;
};
```

But this mousedown elements fired after click occurs.

Comment: in order to get specific help, post your relevant code...

Comment: I update my post, could you look at it again ?

Comment: Overriding the mousedown event binding handler won't do anything unless you're binding mousedown events.

Comment: `$(elems).on('mousedown',function(){
    $(this).triggerHandler('click');
});` or trigger() to propagate event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('click') })
```

I'm not sure though for what this should be useful.

To prevent the second click (which is the normal click) you have to do some extra work

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(e.target).trigger('click').once('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```